# How to write constexpr function which operate on forwarded tuple of reference?

Tags: c++, c++17

I have written a constexpr function which calculate the sum of the sizes of the elements of a tuple.

When called directly, the function call compiles with both tuple of values, and tuple of references.

When called through a templated function, it still compiles with tuple of values, but fail with tuple of references.

I can work around my problem using tuple of pointers instead of tuple of reference, but the API of the thing I write (a templated set of functions to ease writing SPI and I²C driver for microcontrollers) will be less clean.

Thanks for any help.

Ps: I am using gcc8.2 using c++17 standard.

Alexandre

```
#include <tuple>

template <typename> struct is_tuple_t: std::false_type {};
template <typename ...T> struct is_tuple_t<std::tuple<T...>> : std::true_type {};

template<typename Type>
constexpr bool is_tuple(const Type&) {
    if constexpr (is_tuple_t<Type>::value) 
        return true;
    else
        return false;
}

template<class F, class...Ts, std::size_t...Is>
constexpr void for_each_in_tuple(const std::tuple<Ts...> & tupl, F func,
             std::index_sequence<Is...>){
    using expander = int[];
    (void)expander { 0, ((void)func(std::get<Is>(tupl)), 0)... };
}

template<class F, class...Ts>
constexpr void for_each_in_tuple(const std::tuple<Ts...> & tupl, F func){
    for_each_in_tuple(tupl, func, std::make_index_sequence<sizeof...(Ts)>());
}

template <typename T>
constexpr size_t size_of_tuple(const T &tup) {
    static_assert(is_tuple(tup) == true, "error size_of_tuple argument must be a tuple");
    size_t s=0;
    for_each_in_tuple(tup, [&s](auto &&x) {
        s += sizeof(x);
    });
    return s;
}

template<typename Tb>
constexpr size_t foo(const Tb&& tup)
{
    constexpr size_t st = size_of_tuple(tup);
    return st;
}

int main()
{
    uint16_t var;

    constexpr size_t s1 = size_of_tuple(std::make_tuple(1)) ;          // OK
    constexpr size_t s2 = size_of_tuple(std::forward_as_tuple(var)) ;  // OK

    constexpr size_t f1 = foo(std::make_tuple(1)) ;          // OK
    constexpr size_t f2 = foo(std::forward_as_tuple(var)) ;  // FAIL
}
```

Comment: @Rakete1111 is this because foo expects an rvalue and `forward_as_tuple` returns an lvalue reference, in the failing case?

Comment: @Rakete1111 Ah I misread the [return type](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/tuple/forward_as_tuple) on `foward_as_tuple`. | EDIT: Meaning it does return an rvalue. However, I thought forwarding references couldn't make use of `const`.

Comment: Note that removing the intermediate variable `st` in `foo` will allow this to compile.

Comment: @Rakete1111 `Tb` is not a forwarding reference.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
template<typename Tb>
constexpr size_t foo(const Tb&& tup)
{
  constexpr size_t st = size_of_tuple(tup);
  return st;
}
```

In this function, `tup` is not a constant expression, so it can't be used in the initializer of a `constexpr` variable.

> **[expr.const]¶2**
>
> An expression `e` is a *core constant expression* unless the evaluation of `e` [...] would evaluate one of the following expressions:
>
> - [...]
> - an *id-expression* that refers to a variable or data member of reference type unless the reference has a preceding initialization and either
>
>   - it is initialized with a constant expression or
>   - its lifetime began within the evaluation of `e`

Either one of these should work instead:

```
template<typename Tb>
constexpr size_t foo(const Tb&& tup)
{
  size_t st = size_of_tuple(tup);
  return st;
}

template<typename Tb>
constexpr size_t foo(const Tb&& tup)
{
  return size_of_tuple(tup);
}
```

Note that Clang still rejects your code, for other violations of the same rule.

---

Ultimately, your `size_of_tuple` and `is_tuple` are both flawed, as they can't be used in constant expressions if their argument is a reference. If you want to use this function-like syntax, you need something like `type_c` from Boost.Hana:

```
template <typename T>
class type {};
template <typename T>
constexpr type<T> type_c{};

template <typename T>
constexpr bool is_tuple(type<T>) {
    return is_tuple_t<T>::value;
}

template <typename T>
constexpr size_t size_of_tuple(type<T> tup) {
    static_assert(is_tuple(tup), "size_of_tuple argument must be a tuple");
    //...
}

template<typename Tb>
constexpr size_t foo(const Tb&& tup)
{
  size_t st = size_of_tuple(type_c<std::remove_cvref_t<decltype(tup)>>);
  return st;
}

uint16_t var = 42;
constexpr size_t f2 = foo(std::forward_as_tuple(var));
```

Comment: The code i wrote is a simplification of actual code, if the real function i need st to be constexpr because i declare an std::array<uint8_t, st> with the value. So is there any mean to make tup a constant expression ?

Comment: @user3897188 No. You don't need the value of `tup`, only its type. You could construct a local `remove_cvref_t<decltype(tup)>` and use that instead of `tup`, but a tuple of references is not default-constructible.

Comment: thanks to point me to boost.hana, i have read the documentation, and it made my mind more clear.
 
Following your advice, i have been able to rewrite  size_of_tuple :

Answer (score 1):

The problems of your original approach are properly explained in [Oktalist's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/54619712/2615118).

Note that `size_of_tuple` can be implemented in one line using [C++17's fold expressions](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/fold):

```
template<class... Ts>
constexpr std::size_t size_of_tuple(const std::tuple<Ts...>&) {
  return (0 + ... + sizeof(Ts));
}
```

However, that function is hard to use because of the argument of type `const std::tuple<Ts...>&`. Thus it may be desirable to introduce an empty tag type that can be "passed" to these kind of metafunctions. This idea is explained in [`Boost.Hana`'s chapter on type computations](https://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_69_0/libs/hana/doc/html/index.html#tutorial-type).

The following is a complete example.

```
static_assert(__cplusplus >= 201703L, "C++17 required");

#include <cstddef>
#include <cstdint>

#include <tuple>

// the empty tag type
template<class T>
struct Type {};

////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////

template<class... Ts>
constexpr std::size_t size_of_tuple(Type< std::tuple<Ts...> >) {
  return (0 + ... + sizeof(Ts));
}

static_assert(0 == size_of_tuple(Type< std::tuple<> >{}));
static_assert(12 == size_of_tuple(Type< std::tuple<int32_t, int64_t> >{}));
static_assert(12 == size_of_tuple(Type< std::tuple<int32_t&, int64_t&> >{}));
static_assert(2 == size_of_tuple(Type< std::tuple<char&, char> >{}));
static_assert(6 == size_of_tuple(Type< std::tuple<int32_t&, char&, char> >{}));

// fails to compile (for good reasons):
//static_assert(8 == size_of_tuple(Type< std::tuple<int32_t, uint64_t> >{}));
```

Furthermore, you can consider to use [`std::integral_constant`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/types/integral_constant) as return type. That may become handy when you want to pass the size into another function and use it as a `constexpr` value. Note that `std::integral_constant`s are implicitly convertible to their `::type`. The implicit conversion is one reason why `Boost.Hana` introduces its own "integral-constant type". Some interesting examples can be found in [`Boost.Hana`'s chapter on Compile-time numbers](https://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_69_0/libs/hana/doc/html/index.html#tutorial-integral). Anyway, here is the simple example with the implicitly convertible `std::integral_constant`:

```
#include <cstddef>

#include <tuple>
#include <type_traits>

template<class... Ts>
constexpr auto better_size_of_tuple(Type< std::tuple<Ts...> >) {
  constexpr std::size_t ret = (0 + ... + sizeof(Ts));
  return std::integral_constant<std::size_t, ret>{};
}
```

Answer (score 0):

so here is a rewrite of the function which compile, at least with gcc 8.2 :

```
template
<std::size_t position, class T>
struct SizeOfTupImpl{
static constexpr size_t
size() {
  if constexpr (position != 0) {
  return sizeof(std::tuple_element_t<position, T>) +
         SizeOfTupImpl<position - 1, T>::size();
  } else {
  return sizeof(std::tuple_element_t<0, T>);
  }
}
};

template<class T>
constexpr size_t
size_of_tuple(const T& tup) {
  static_assert(is_tuple(tup) == true, "error size_of_tuple argument must be a tuple");
  constexpr std::size_t dimension = std::tuple_size<T>::value;
  return SizeOfTupImpl<dimension - 1, T>::size();
}
```

Since i am an absolute template metaprogramming beginner, feel free to point me toward a more elegant solution !

Alexandre